# Need more Columns in select clause which are not in Group by clause

Tags: oracle

Hi i have table like below and data

```
  create  table temp12 (PARTY_ID number,PARTY_NAME varchar2(30),PARTY_NUMBER varchar2(50),WORK_PHONE_NUMBER varchar2(30),EMAIL_ADDRESS varchar2(30),RELATIONSHIP_NAME varchar2(10),BUSINESS_OR_PERSONAL varchar2(50));

insert into temp12 values (100,'xyz','CONTACT-1042','1-(800)5558355','nobody@localhost','Bill To','Business');
insert into temp12 values(100,'xyz','CONTACT-1042','1-(800)5558355',null,'Bill To','Business');
insert into temp12 values(100,'xyz','CONTACT-1042',null,'nobody@localhost','Bill To','personal');
```

i need to have email column in select clause in order to display in UI .In my scenario 2nd row can be considered as duplicate but already party is having phone and email with same type Business..i need to remove like this records

with below select statement i can achieve unique records, but i want workphone and email columns..in select clause.

Comment: **a)** INSERT INTO contains more values than table TEMP12 has columns, so inserts fail, **b)** There are no aggregates, so - instead of GROUP BY, use DISTINCT, **c)** What is desired result? **d)** Looks like you're missing the WHERE clause which would filter data you don't need

Comment: There's nothing I'd like to add to my previous comment (except maybe an objection: as if you're desperately trying NOT to get help).

Comment: How to add my original query as file?

Comment: Hi , actually i have given sample data which will fit my original issue. we have select clause and where condition and distinct as well..as i said in our original data also..we are getting total 3 records, out of which 2nd record should be duplicate one. –

Comment: Post the desired output you are looking to achieve and also provide working create table statements so people can help

Comment: @Beefstu, thanks for your rpely, i have already changed create statement and now no error will come.

Comment: You want to remove rows from your results that don't add information. Row #1 has all the information row #2 has plus the email address. So, row #2 must be removed from the results. I suppose the same can occur with the work phone number (one row has it, the other not). Are there more columns, beside email address and work phone number that can be null in one row and not null in the other? And am I right assuming that if we removed the work phone number from row #1, then you would want to show all three rows?

Comment: You could use `min(EMAIL_ADDRESS) as EMAIL_ADDRESS`.

Comment: What does the table actually represent? It's not parties, because in that case each party would be just once in the table. To me it looks very much like a broken database design, because data seems to be stored redundantly. Then, however, you call the table temp12, so maybe you created it ad hoc to solve some problem. In that case, can't you just fill it properly right away, instead of having to clean it up later?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner
i have posted my original query in order to avoid confusion..so we are using this query in order to show party contact details in UI..Yes row #2 should not bring this select stmnt..as #1 row is already having information

Comment: Alright. This query seems to be more than 20 years old as we can see from the deprecated Oracle join syntax. If I were in your situation I would write this query completely anew with proper explicit joins. Then it may be possible to avoid getting those half filled rows with the right mixture of inner, outer, and lateral joins, in/exists clauses and subqueries,

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, is there any suggestion can we change with existing code as bcz this is product code and i cannot change completely, any suggestions to avoid that half filled information rows .

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have any advice. I'd have to know the tables and their data in order to decide how to get information from these tables. Do I need every row or just the "best" rows, e.g. the newest row per xyz? Or do I need aggregation results? The hz_contact_points looks like a form of a key/value table. There you might use conditional aggregation to get one row per key with a column for every attribute. Writing this query anew is some work, but it is probably worth it, because it may run faster and get the correct data and most of all it will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: Ok thanks @thorstenkettner I am trying to rewriting the query